# How to assign by GPO a file/shortcut to desktop for both specific user and computer?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

**I have to put on my domain controler's desktops only a custom MMC for a specific user only.**

Tought the best course of action was:

*Default_DC_OU containing DCs, applying the GPO for shortcut to MMC.
that worked on DCs only but that was not user-specific yet.

*Apply filtering on target-user-group by adding it and after removing authenticated users deleguation the GPO doesnt work at all.

I've dug into policies loopback processing but it seems it wouldnt help since i try to use a computer based policy.

**How do i make it happen?**

Comment: Please don't log into a domain controller (or any other server) to manage it with an interactive session. Use remote management consoles and CLI instead.

Comment: Its straightforward to see how bad this would be in production, hopefully this was only asked for an academic purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Considered just creating the mmc and saving it to a central location on the network. Assigning permissions to this directory only to the users that need it. Then in your group policy just have a script that runs to create the shortcut in the public user directory, or under the root system drive.

Comment: Exactly what i've done so far. Could it be adjusted so that it doesnt appear on other desktops than target-user? I'd go for adding filtering on target-user-group and removing "apply" from authenticated users deleguation but it doesnt work.

Comment: No, that would be the purpose of setting the ACL, it wouldn't matter what user saw if only set group have access.

Answer (score 0):

A user based group policy using group policy preferences is likeliest the easiest way to make this happen.

Username equal to your username
AND
Computername equal to your domain controller.

Comment: "Username equal to your username AND Computername equal to your domain controller." By WMI filtering or straight into the objects filtering? I was applying computer based policy to target-computer-OU, I guess I should apply user based policy on target-user-OU and filter computer there, was that your point?

Comment: @yaku that's why I suggested *group policy preferences*. It's not wmi filtering, it's a user policy bound to a the user ou.